# slicing not returning last element in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

i am writing the following code to get days between 2 days excluding start day

```
df = df.select('CreatedDate', 'ClosedDate')
df = df.withColumn('days', F.expr('sequence(CreatedDate, ClosedDate, interval 1 day)'))\
    .withColumn('days', F.expr('slice(days, 2, size(days))'))\
```

i get the following output

[image]

in some cases the last element is missing (line 1) and in some its present, can someone help me why this is happening?

Comment: i believe it is due to the time elements. in your first case, the last timestamp would've had the time 9:19:51 which is less than the first timestamp's time. since it does not qualify as a complete day, it was not considered in the sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a slicing issue. I believe it is due to the time elements. In your first row, the last timestamp would've had the time `9:19:51` which is less than the first timestamp's time of `13:31:48`. Since it does not qualify as a complete day and given your interval of 1 day, it was not considered in the sequence (a timestamp having the same time as of the first timestamp in the sequence would have qualified).

If you don't need any operations on time, you can get rid of that and then calculate the sequence.

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('days', 
               func.expr('sequence(date_add(to_date(CreatedDate), 1), to_date(ClosedDate), interval 1 day)')
               )
```

Comment: for some reason the date add function is not working well so i did the following.
df = df.withColumn('days', F.expr('sequence(to_date(CreatedDate), to_date(ClosedDate), interval 1 day)'))\
            .withColumn('days', F.expr('slice(days, 2, size(days))'))\

thank you for pointing out that it was because of hours and casting to date would solve. This helps.

Comment: i must calculate the difference in hours from start to end date that is a result after excluding weekends, your solution solves days issue but i wont be able to calculate the difference b/w 2 days in hours accurately because with to_date i lose the timestamp. 

anyways i can solve this?

Comment: @ArunMohan - the difference will always be 24 hours even with timestamps because you're using `interval 1 day`

Comment: thank you for the response, i figured it out.
created a new variable and used interval as "1 hour" to get hourly difference.